# efficient javafx fadetransition

Tags: javafx, fade

I have a large amount of nodes and currently using fade trasition code below,

```
ft1 = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), hBox_outter_last);
                                       ft1.setFromValue(1.0);
                                        ft1.setToValue(0.3);
                                        ft1.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                                        ft1.setAutoReverse(true);
                                       ft1.play();
```

however this is CPU consuming and was told that I can use the following, however this does not work, anyone can help with this

```
DoubleProperty opacity = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
Transition opacityTransition = new Transition() {
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        opacity.set(frac);
    }
};

// elsewhere
hBox_outter_last.opacityProperty().bind(opacity);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the `cycleDuration` (and I assume you are calling `play()` somewhere...):

```
Transition opacityTransition = new Transition() {
    {
        setCycleDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
    }
    protected void interpolate(double frac) {
        opacity.set(frac);
    }
};
```

If that doesn't fix it, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I assumed that's what the transition was for... maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: still consumes large amount of CPU time, when using setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);